# Pulling an NSArray out of a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an NSMutableArray which is storing a list of other arrays. And when i run the code.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[appDelegate teamRoster]objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]class])
```

It returns and tells me that i am looking at an Array,

however when i try to do the following

```
[selectedRowerView tempArray] = [[appDelegate teamRoster]objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]];
```

The program errors out. Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: You're looking for the problem on the wrong side of the `=` assignment operator. ;) See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that `[selectedRowerView tempArray]` is actually a command / message that is being sent.  In C++ equivalent, you are calling `selectedRowerView->tempArray() = ...`.  Which doesn't make logical sense because you cannot make an assignment to a function.

What you're trying to do is set the tempArray.  If you have the proper setters/getters set-up, you can just run: `selectedRowerView.tempArray = ...;`

Just make sure that tempArray has a `@property` and is `@synthesize`'d.

Comment: im still getting **expected ':' before ']' token** any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, i had it as [indexPath.row], but i needed indexPath.row.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
selectedRowerView.tempArray = [[appDelegate teamRoster]objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]];
```

…assuming that `tempArray` is a synthesized property à la

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSArray *tempArray;

@synthesize tempArray;
```

---

Clarification:

```
selectedRowerView.tempArray = …;
```

gets internally processed to

```
[selectedRowerView setTempArray:…];
```

which is a **setter method**.

While

```
selectedRowerView.tempArray;
```

gets internally processed to

```
[selectedRowerView tempArray];
```

which is a **getter method**.

Subtle but important difference.
The meaning of `foo.bar` depends on the very context (enclosing expression) it is used in.